# Cypher - What is the deference between myNode <> NULL and myNode IS NOT NULL?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two test queries

```
CREATE (a:TEST)
DELETE a
WITH a
WHERE a <> NULL
RETURN (a:TEST)
```

Which returns

```
Added 1 label, created 1 node, deleted 1 node, statement completed in 0 ms.
```

And

```
CREATE (a:TEST)
DELETE a
WITH a
WHERE a IS NOT NULL
RETURN (a:TEST)
```

Which returns

```
Node with id 1738 has been deleted in this transaction
```

According to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#query-operators-comparison), "<>" is the inequality operator. So my understanding is that "a <> NULL" and "a IS NOT NULL" are equivalent in Cypher. At the very least, I would expect "a IS NOT NULL" to be the more reliable filter (as it is its own dedicated compare operator). This seems like it might be an edge case bug of creating and deleting a node in the same transaction, but the documentation on IS NOT NULL doesn't say anything beyond (implied) "it is an operator", so this could be intentional if there is a subtle deference.

**So why does `a <> NULL` work when `a IS NOT NULL` doesn't? AKA, What is the deference between these two comparisons?**

I am using Cypher version 3.1, and Neo4j version 3.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cypher, NULL is used to represent missing or undefined values. Thus equality tests involving NULL will always be undefined also - which is treated as false. See https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/working-with-null/ for details.

In your example, the identifier `a` continues to refer to a node, even after the `DELETE a`. It is not NULL. In the first example, you are comparing a non-NULL identifier to NULL, which is always unknown and thus false. Hence the `RETURN a` never gets evaluated and you only see output about the creation and deletion.

In the second example, the check is `a IS NOT NULL`, which is true. `a` refers to a node that has been deleted from the graph. So the clause `RETURN a` is evaluated.

You receive the error `Node with id 1738 has been deleted in this transaction` because the rendering of the node tries to read the node from the graph, where it has been deleted. It is debatable that, rather than an error, the node representation should still be returned. The argument that the identifier `a` continues to reference the node has merit. However, at this time, Neo4j doesn't provide the kind of isolation required to achieve this and I do not believe the OpenCypher group has a position on whether it should or should not work that way.

Comment: And now I notice I was using RETURN (a:TEST), instead of RETURN a; So a was returning a pattern match, not the deleted node. In which case the return should probably be null. Thanks!

Comment: You're right. With just `RETURN a`, you'd not get an error and an empty node would be returned. With `(a:Test)`, it's trying to match in the graph by ID again, and the node is no longer available for matching. Arguably, it shouldn't need to match again, given `a` already references the node - in which case all that would be required would be a filter to assert the `:Test` label.